# Handle exceptions during modifications on a csv with spring batch

Tags: java, spring, csv

I got a huge csv file. I want to modify this file via spring batch. I used the FlatFileItemReader and the FlatFileItemWriter. What happens if an exception is thrown during the execution of spring batch? What i want is the following:

If an error occurred during the execution of spring batch, i want to skip this row and keep on the modification of the csv. At the end of the spring batch process i want to see which rows lead to an error, and thus, could not be written.

Let's say an error occurs in the ItemProcessor:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;

public class MyItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Product, ArrayList<String>> {

@Override
public ArrayList<String> process(final Product product) throws Exception {

    if (product.getId().equals("PRODUCT_ID210")) {
        BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal(130);
        product.setPrice(price);
    }

    if (product.getId().equals("PRODUCT_ID211")) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    if (product.getId().equals("PRODUCT_ID21")) {
        BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal(140);
        product.setPrice(price);
    }

    return product.getDetails();

}
```

}

In this situation spring batch stops with error message:
ERROR executor-1      (AbstractStep.java:222) : Encountered an error executing the step
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at job.batch.MyItemProcessor.process(MyItemProcessor.java:20)

Sure, i could write a try-catch, but this is not what we want, is it?

Btw: the csv looks like
PRODUCT_ID;NAME;DESCRIPTION;PRICE
PRODUCT_ID210;BlackBerry 8100 Pearl;A cell phone;124.60
PRODUCT_ID211;Sony Ericsson W810i;Yet another cell phone!;139.45
PRODUCT_ID212;Samsung MM-A900M Ace;A cell phone;97.80
PRODUCT_ID213;Toshiba M285-E 14;A cell phone;166.20
PRODUCT_ID214;Nokia 2610 Phone;A cell phone;145.50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution were annotations @OnSkipInRead @OnSkipInProcess @OnSkipInWrite and some skippable-exception-classes with a skipListener.